# Which Linux filesystem is best for a huge Apache mod_disk_cache partition?

Tags: apache-2.2, filesystems, cache, disk-cache

Talking about a huge (50GB, 500.000 entries) Apache disk_cache partition: Which Linux filesystem performs best for this task?

In my example, the partition has a lot (500.000) of very small files (< 1 KB) and a lot (500.000) of files with ~ 50 KB.

File hierarchy is as deep as `/htcache/B/x/i_iGfmmHhxJRheg8NHcQ.header.vary/A/W/oGX3MAV3q0bWl30YmA_A.header`.

Typical actions are creating directories and files (by Apache), reading files (Apache) and removing files and directories (htcacheclean).

I'm currently using **ext3** and I'm facing bad performance (i.e. slow ops with high IOwaits) when purging outdated files and emptied directories from the cache.

- the ext3 filesystem was created with "-t news" (i.e. `blocksize = 4096`, `inode_size = 256` and `inode_ratio = 4096`).
- filesystem features: "`has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file`"
- the partition is mounted with "`noatime`"

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if using a non-journalling FS is an option (or turning journaling off in ext3). You could also try some ext3 tuning options - like noatime - tune2fs could help.

Btrfs is the new buzzFS at the moment... from the benhcmarks I've seen, it is comparable to (or better than) ext4. If I were starting with a new system, I'd prefer (tuned) ext4, then maybe btrfs, then (tuned) ext3 for may small files. I'd hesitate about ext2: old and stable and has no journalling, but haven't really seen it compared to the current ext3/ext4/btrfs.

You probably should not not go with XFS for many small files.

Comment: I'm already using noatime (question edited, thanks!). I thought that ext3 without journal is almost identical to ext2? Regarding tune2fs, I  looked into that, but saw nothing else to tune besides removing the journal (see my filesystem features in the edited question). Any hints?

Comment: No, sorry - I lack experience beyond that. Yes, ext3 with no journal is ext2, but I don't know how journalling impacts performance in your case. You mentioned slow performance during purge - maybe you could use `ionice -c 3` on the purge cron job? That could really help, at the cost of slower purge. As you most likely understand yourself, testing a few options under your specific load would be best - provided you have time and resources to do that.

Comment: I removed the journal (`tune2fs -O ^has_journal`) and mounted the partition as ext2. Didn't help, the IOwaits even went further up. Luckily, `tune2fs -O has_journal` reinstalled the journal, so that I'm now back to ext3.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm really curious what is the best FS option for your case. This post - http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.cassandra.user/8478 - suggests that ext4 might be superior to ext3 with high inode counts. Seems at least partially relevant.